# 2x vCenter Essentials on 1 host

Tags: vmware-vcenter

As we consider the vSphere Standard kit (vCenter Standard+vSphere) proportionally too expensive in comparison with Essentials Plus Kit, we would buy 2x Essentials Kit. But the question is, is it possible to run 2 instances of vCenter Essentials on 1 host with Windows2008 ? Or it must be 1 host = 1 vCenter ?

Comment: Why would you need to run 2 instances? Can you not install both Kit licenses in one vCenter instance?

Comment: Essentials kits are limited to three hosts, no way to upgrade or expand that.

Comment: Look, I need 6 hosts support (actually 2x group by 3). It is cheaper to get 2 Essentials Plus Kit licenses than 1x Standard Kit. So why not go this way and pay the money you are not forced to pay. That's why I'm asking this question.

Comment: You'd be better off asking your licensing vendor.

Comment: @HampusLI: I understand the licensing I'm asking if it's possible to install the licenses from 2 Essentials Kits in 1 vCenter instance.

Comment: @Mejmo: I didn't mean any offense. I asked my question because I'm curious as to whether or not you can install the licenses for 2 Essentials Kits in 1 vCenter instance. I'm not questioning your choice. My question was for my own edification.

Comment: @joeqwerty: No you cannot add two essential licenses to a vCenter Essential.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not supported (and I don't think it's actually *possible*) to install two instances of vCenter on the same server.

But if you are short on hardware, you can install them on two virtual servers; it's totally supported to run vCenter on a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2):

You could run two VM's with totally separate vCenter essential install.

However buying Esssential seriously locks you in without an upgrade /scaling path. Standard licensing will cost more initially but you will not loose that investment when you scale up.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but you are not right actually - Essentials pack can be upgraded to one of the higher licenses - [Vmware vSphere Essentials Upgrade Path](http://it-services.netlogix.de/fileadmin/user_upload/IT-Services/PDF/VMware/VMware_vSphere_4.1_Cheatsheet.pdf)

Comment: I did this for a little while while we transferred data off our old VMware cluster (3.5) to the new cluster (4.1).  As long as they are different VMs it works perfectly.

Comment: @mejmo: Good news, not much of a discount on the upgrades though. At least something.

Comment: Moreover, the result of upgrade to Standard is 6 processors. Not 8, as the Standard edition is.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it, buy installing another vCenter in Hyper-V virtual machine on that host.